# How do I add a value to an array that is a property of an object?

Tags: object, multidimensional-array, properties

593/5000
Hello,
I have the following object:

```
let rover{
x:0,
y:0,
direction:"S",
travelLog:[[0,0],[0,1]]
}
```

I want to add a value to the travelLog property which is an array of arrays (pairs of x, y coordinates in each box);
I tried `rover.traveLog.push ([x, y]);` which doesn't work and returns
rover.travelLog.push is not a function error.
I tried to put rover.travelLog in a travel variable then:
`travel.push ([x, y]);` same mistake.
How can I add items to this array?
Each time I move my rover, I must save the new coordinates in the corresponding travelLog.
Thank you for your help,
Virginie

Comment: First of all you are missing the equal sign let rower=. Second mistake you have traveLog instead but in rover is travelLog, see one more lowercase L

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @Hoppo looks like javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found out where the problem came from. In fact my syntaxes were correct. But only the name of the rover (string) was given as a parameter of the encompassing function instead of the object itself. Therefore "rover.travelLog" did not point to any object.